# How to capture 802.11 packets using pcap library on Windows using Rust

Tags: rust, wifi, pcap

I'm currently working on a project where I need to capture 802.11 packets using the pcap library in Rust on a Windows environment. I enable Monitor Mode using `wlanhelper.exe`

Here is a sample of my code:

```
use pcap::*;
fn capture_wpa2_handshake(
    interface_index:usize
) {
    // List available devices and choose the one you want
    let device = Device::list().unwrap()[interface_index].clone();
    // Choose the device (you may need to change the index based on your setup)


    // Open the selected device for capturing
    let mut cap = device.open().unwrap();
    let mut savefile = cap.savefile("test.pcap").unwrap();
    // Keep capturing until the 4-way handshake is complete
    let mut handshake_complete = false;
    // Set a filter to capture only TCP packets
    cap.filter("ether proto 0x888e", true).unwrap();
    while !handshake_complete {
        if let Ok(packet) = cap.next_packet() {
            // Process the packet, check if it's part of the WPA2 4-way handshake
            // You need to implement the logic to identify EAPOL-Key messages
            // and keep track of the handshake state
            println!("Received packet: {:?}", packet);

            // Check if the WPA2 4-way handshake is complete
            // You need to implement the logic to detect the completion of the handshake
        handshake_complete = is_wpa2_handshake_complete(&packet);
        // handshake_complete = true;
        savefile.write(&packet);
        }

    }
    println!("WPA2 4-way handshake complete!");
}
```

The problem I face I can't capture any packets using pcap, but Wireshark can.

Comment: is your Rust app running as admin ? did you check that the `interface_index` you're using is the correct network interface ? (and is the one Wireshark is using) Also, you should check if the interface remains in Monitor mode when your Rust app is running

Comment: Yes, the Rust app is running as an admin. The interface_index being used is verified to be the correct network interface, and it aligns with the one Wireshark is using. Additionally, I checked that the interface remains in monitor mode consistently while the Rust app is running.